# send sql server query result to all computers in lan

Tags: c#, python, sql-server, batch-file

I have a lan network of simulation games room. all the statistics saves on a ms server db.

I am searching for an easy way to send a query result to all the computers in the lan network.

Something like - when I run some script or application. all the players will get a pop up screen with the query result like - number of kills, number of team deads, etc.

There is an easy way to do it? with c#, batch file, python, some downloadable application or any other way?

---

EDIT:
All the computers has windows 7

Comment: You want to send game stats to all comps. You don't need help with the query itself, right ?

Comment: I need help of how i get some query text and send the text to other computers. maybe it will help - all the computers with win7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to send information, without any backchannel and without any other requirements, Windows has a tool to send messages to users or computers over the network.

[Net Send](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490710.aspx). It should already be installed on Windows machines, all you have to do is use it.

Comment: How i get the query text to send it with that NetSend? tnx

Comment: Use whatever tool you use to connect to your database. A batch script maybe? A small C# program? Whatever is the easiest for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, this is the same as sending any message between computers. There are various approaches, but most commonly:

- have the app poll intermittently
- use a broadcast mechanism
- use a pub/sub mechanism

I'm a big fan of the last, which can be done trivially with redis. Just have the client apps create a redis connection and subscribe to a named channel:

```
sub.Subscribe("AWOOGA", (channel, message) => {
    DoSomethingWith((string)message);
});
```

and have one of the nodes publish:

```
sub.Publish("AWOOGA", "Launch the missiles!");
```

That's it. The above examples are using the StackExchange.Redis client library [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/). You will need a redis server, but that is also [freely available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Redis-64/).